# How to pass my User object data to ASPX page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm just trying to do something really simple here in ASP.net (ASPX), and it doesn't seem to be working.

I have the following class/Model, View and Controller:

**Users.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ASPWebsite.Models
{
    public class Users
    {
        private string firstName;
        private string lastName;

        public Users(string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public string GetFirstName()
        {
            return this.firstName;
        }

        public string GetLastName()
        {
            return this.lastName;
        }
    }
}
```

**Index.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<ASPWebsite.Models.Users>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Index
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h2>Index</h2>

<h2><%Model.GetFirstName();%></h2>

</asp:Content>
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

using ASPWebsite.Models;

namespace ASPWebsite.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

            var user = new Users("foo", "bar");

            return View(user);
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have created a User with the name foo bar and passed it to the view, but when I run it, it doesn't display the name. What is wrong with it??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `<h2><%: Model.GetFirstName() %></h2>`

Comment: nvm, forgot to delete the ; at the end Thanks